# How to Get Value From an Array within a JS Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a value from an array within an object.

This is the data:

```
{
    "Order Number":102541029, 
    "Tracking Number":192048236154915,
    "Secondary Tracking":87350125235,
    "Items":[{
     "SKU":"0200-02-01-NP-P-00",
     "QTY":4
    },
    {
     "SKU":"0120-02-01-XP-T-00",
     "QTY":2
    }]
   }
```

If I wanted, say, the quantity of the second item (SKU 0120-02-01-XP-T-00), how would I select this?

I've tried a few things like this:

```
var skuQty = datain.items.['0120-02-01-XP-T-00'].['QTY'];
```

That's the idea, but I am not using the right syntax obviously. Any help here?

- Jesse

Comment: I'd start off by reviewing the documentation for arrays. For instance, [MDN's documentation for Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you scroll through the quantities:

```js
var yourObject = {
    "Order Number":102541029, 
    "Tracking Number":192048236154915,
    "Secondary Tracking":87350125235,
    "Items":[{
     "SKU":"0200-02-01-NP-P-00",
     "QTY":4
    },
    {
     "SKU":"0120-02-01-XP-T-00",
     "QTY":2
    }]
   };

var items = yourObject.Items;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
    console.log(items[i].QTY);
}
```

In general you can access an array with its index something like this: `arr[i]` and object can be accessed by it's key name:

```
 `yourObject.yourkey`
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, select the specified object - in your case - `data`.

Then select specified `key` from the `data` object - in your case - `Items`.

Since `Items` is an array with two objects, you have to specify which one of them you are interested in. In your case - the second one with index `1`.

`data.Items[1]` is an object holding two positions. You are interested in the second one - so you just type that key name - `QTY`.

Adding it up together - **`data.Items[1].QTY`**.

```js
var data = {
  "Order Number": 102541029,
  "Tracking Number": 192048236154915,
  "Secondary Tracking": 87350125235,
  "Items": [{
    "SKU": "0200-02-01-NP-P-00",
    "QTY": 4
  }, {
    "SKU": "0120-02-01-XP-T-00",
    "QTY": 2
  }]
};

console.log(data.Items[1].QTY)
```

Answer (score 1):

in JavaScript, an `array = [1,2,3]` can be accessed with `array[index]`.

If you have an array that looks like this: `array = [{ prop: propValue }]`, then this is virtually the same as `obj = { prop: propValue }; array = [ obj ]`, so what you need to do to get `propValue` is `array[ 0 ]['prop']`.

For your specific case, you'd need

`datain.Items[1]['SKU'];`

Now, what you actually want to do is filter through the array items until the above value is `"0120-02-01-XP-T-00"`

This is literally filtering an array:

`datain.Items.filter( function( obj ){ return obj['SKU'] === "0120-02-01-XP-T-00" } )[0]['QTY']`

The key is that `array.filter( fn )` returns a new array of values for which `fn( item [, other parameters you don't need to worry about] )` is `true` (or truthy). At that point, you only need the first item, at `index = 0`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get it:

```
Object {Order Number: 102541029, Tracking Number: 192048236154915, Secondary Tracking: 87350125235, Items: Array[2]}
obj.Items[0]
Object {SKU: "0200-02-01-NP-P-00", QTY: 4}
obj.Items[0].QTY
```

```js
obj =  {
    "Order Number":102541029, 
    "Tracking Number":192048236154915,
    "Secondary Tracking":87350125235,
    "Items":[{
     "SKU":"0200-02-01-NP-P-00",
     "QTY":4
    },
    {
     "SKU":"0120-02-01-XP-T-00",
     "QTY":2
    }]
   };
console.log(obj.Items[0].QTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `items` is an array, you need to select the appropriate index of the array, in this case 1.
For example:

> var skuQty = datain.items[1].QTY;

Comment: Ty, edited the code block with the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()`, at callback return `o.SKU === "0120-02-01-XP-T-00"`, where `o` is current object in iteration use bracket notation to select element at index `0` of returned array

```
var QTY = data.Items.filter(function(o) {
            return o.SKU === "0120-02-01-XP-T-00"
          })[0]["QTY"];
```

You can alternatively utilize destructuring assignment

```
var [, {QTY}] = data.Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to find order items for a given SKU:

```
var findOrderItem = function (order, sku) {
  if (order && order.Items) {
    for (var i = 0; i < order.Items.length; i++) {
      if (order.Items[i].SKU == sku) {
        return order.Items[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};
var myOrder = {
  "Order Number": 102541029,
  "Tracking Number": 192048236154915,
  "Secondary Tracking": 87350125235,
  "Items": [
    {
      "SKU": "0200-02-01-NP-P-00",
      "QTY": 4
    },
    {
      "SKU": "0120-02-01-XP-T-00",
      "QTY": 2
    }
  ]
};
var sku = "0120-02-01-XP-T-00";
var item = findOrderItem(myOrder, sku);
var qty = 0;
if (item) {
  qty = item.QTY;
}
console.log("item qty", qty);
```